# Presigned S3 URL for PUT with dynamic filename / key starts with

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

Is it possible to PUT to S3 using a presigned key-starts-with policy to allow upload of multiple or arbitrarily named files?

This is easy using the browser-based PresignedPost technique, but I've been unable to find a way to use a normal simple PUT for uploading arbitrary files starting with the same key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't possible... not directly.

`POST` uploads are unique in their support for an embedded policy document, which allows logic like starts-with.

`PUT` and all other requests require the signature to precisely match the request, because the signature is derived entirely from observable attributes of the request itself.

One possible workaround would be to connect the bucket to CloudFront and use a CloudFront pre-signed URL with an appropriate wildcard.  The CloudFront origin access identity, after validating the CloudFront URL, would actually handle signing the request in the background on its way to S3 to match the exact request.  Giving the origin access identity the `s3:PutObject` permission in bucket policy then should allow the action.

I suggest this should work, though I have not tried it, because the CloudFront docs indicate that the client needs to add the `x-amz-content-sha256` header to `PUT` requests for full compatibility with all S3 regions.  The same page warns that any permissions you assign to the origin access identity will work (such as `DELETE`), so, setting the bucket policy too permissive will allow any operation to be performed via the signed URL -- CloudFront signed URLs don't restrict to a specific REST verb.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-restricting-access-to-s3.html

Note that there's no such concept as uploading "to" CloudFront.  Uploads go *through* CloudFront to the origin server, S3 in this case.

Comment: Thank you. Great answer. I guess another option in my case, which is uploading from Objective C, would be to replicate a multi-part form upload with a POST. I've tried this a few times, but AWS is not great at giving feedback on what's wrong.

Comment: You said: "POST uploads are unique in their support for an embedded policy document, which allows logic like starts-with.". But I can't anywhere find the information on how to generate presigned url that would allow me to upload files with dynamic name using POST method. I'm so frustrated with the S3 docs and lack of any sane information on it anywhere...

Comment: @Mikz you don't sign the URL when you're doing a `POST` upload.  The upload is formatted as `multipart/form-data` and the signature goes in a form field. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-post-example.html